# How do I display all the nodes for multiple Organic Groups?

Tags: organic-groups, views

I have a block that I want to display a slideshow of all the logos in a Group based on the OG of the node I am viewing.

For example, I'm viewing a node that has a “Coffee” OG, and in the block I want see the logo that is also in “coffee” OG.

I works fine works I'm viewing a node that has only one group, but when I'm on a node that has multiple OGs, it only ever displays one logo. How can I get the view to recognize the node I'm viewing has multiple OGs and then display all the logos that also have that OG.

Right now, I'm showing the logo blog like this:

In 'Advanced':

Contextual filters:
(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group ID

Relationships
OG membership: OG membership from Node

In 'Filter criteria':

Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Type (= Logo Slideshow)
(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group_type (= Node)

Thanks